# Alternative to maintaining timer at server side for every connected client

Tags: sockets, timer, pthreads, client-server, posix

I have a server side application wherein a timer (for 3 mins)needs to be started at the receipt of first message from client. There can be a maximum of 100 clients connecting to the server. So 100 timers need to maintained for each client in 100 threads(for each client). Is there any alternate solution for maintaining these 100 timers (like using epoll)?

EDIT: The purpose of the timer is to check if any messages come from the client in the next 3 min.If it doesnt come error indication is given.If the message comes within the 3 min, timer expires and restarts again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate solution is just to have one timer, for the client that will be expiring earliest.  When that timer expires (or is cancelled), you set a new timer for the next earliest expiring client.

Comment: Shouldn't we need a timer to identify the client expiring the earliest.In that case, timers will have to be maintained for each client? Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: All you need to do is sort the list of clients by the expiry times to determine the client expiring earliest.